# displaying special characters in android app from sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, textview

I have a Periodic table of elements app for android that stores most of it's data in string arrays.  I am now trying to use an sqlite database instead of the arrays but am having a small problem.  If I type 'android:text="&#185;"' directly into a TextView it will display a superscript 1(like this-> ¹), but if I store '&#185;' as text in a sqlite database and then use a cursor to populate that same TextView, instead of the superscript 1 being displayed I just see "&#185;" exactly as I typed it.  How can I get the TextView to display special characters when being populated by a sqlite database?  I have been struggling for a while and am stumped so any suggestions would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use the [Java Unicode string notation](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b9/index.htm) for each special character when inserting them into your database.
For '¹', that would be: `\u00b9`.

Alternatively, to parse HTML tags and character entities like `&#185;` in a `TextView`, then you can probably wrap the String in a call to [`Html.fromHtml()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String%29) before calling `setText()`.

Comment: I tried the \u00b9 and haven't been able to get it to work.  As for Html.fromHtml(), I'm not sure where to call it because I'm not using setText(), I'm using a ListAdapter.

Comment: How are you populating the database?

Comment: I am creating the database and populating from a command line.

Comment: +1 for Html.fromHtml(). And if you are using a ListAdapter, you'll need to do this in the getView() method of the adapter.